# firebase cloud function: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined for axios package use in typescript code

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, axios, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to host below logic in google cloud function. When I execute this function using the emulator I am always getting `⚠  functions: TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined`

I tried to import the Axios packages in different manner but no success. Is this something to do with my code or am I missing some firebase configuration?

```
import axios from "axios";

export const sendSlackMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const slackUrl = functions.config().slackconfig.webhookurl;
  await axios.post(slackUrl, request.body)
    .then((value) => {
      console.log(value.data);
      response.sendStatus(200);
    })
    .catch((reason) => {
      response.send(`Failed, ${reason}`);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you install it with `$ npm install axios`? Also, what if you deploy the Cloud Function?

Comment: Yup, I had installed it using npm only. Same error even after deploying.
To confirm again, I just cleaned up the functions/node_modules folder and reran `npm install`, The issue still persists.

Comment: Can you try to install with `npm install axios@latest` and update the package to 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed axios in the functions directory

```
 cd functions/
 npm i axios
```

Comment: Yeah I can confirm that I did this only.